# DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jrebel

I am setting up a basic Spring Boot application `(1.2.3.RELEASE)` on `Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4.RELEASE.`

I decided to install jRebel using myJRebel `(6.2.0)`.

When I start my application (`Run as Spring Boot App`), I can't see the jRebel logs in the console. I already checked my project under jRebel config and there is already a `rebel.xml`.

In the logs I found this

```
DEBUG DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch
```

Any possible reason why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is using embedded container, it should have main method. I would try to run it as Java application.

According to [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-hot-swapping), JRebel should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Running the `main()` method as a Java Application works.
I don't why running the project as Spring Boot App doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`unknown type org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch` means that JRebel doesn't have support for that particular launch config and in turn, the JRebel tab doesn't appear in the Run/Debug Configuration panel, so that the VM arguments have to be passed manually (can use `${jrebel_args}` variable). The JRebel tab is added to it in the 6.2.1 release.